# JGit unable to pull in jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, jgit

I'm running into an issue where JGit isn't able to pull from a Gitlab repo during the apps build phase. There are three different repos that are read from while the app builds and two of the three have no issues but for the third repo I'm getting the exception below. All three repos have access tokens for Jenkins. It also doesn't look to be an access issue going by the stacktrace.

From my searching, the ClosedByInterruptException happens when the thread is interrupted. What I can't figure out is why it only happens for that one repo.

Does anyone have an idea of what's causing this?

```
Cloning repo at [redacted] failed

org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.fetch(CloneCommand.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.call(CloneCommand.java:200)
    at com.foo.bar.baz.data.GitDataFactory.getGit(GitDataFactory.java:103)
    at com.foo.bar.baz.data.GitDataFactory.initialize(GitDataFactory.java:50)
    at com.foo.bar.baz.data.GitDataFactory.get(GitDataFactory.java:41)
    at com.foo.bar.baz.config.internal.Config.lambda$GitDataFactoryDependency$0(Config.java:59)
    at com.foo.bar.baz.SimplePing.ping(SimplePing.java:46)
    at com.foo.bar.baz.PingDependency.call(PingDependency.java:184)
    at com.foo.bar.baz.PingDependency.call(PingDependency.java:19)
    at com.foo.bar.baz.Wrapper.call(Wrapper.java:24)
    at com.foo.bar.baz.Wrapper.call(Wrapper.java:11)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackFetchConnection.doFetch(BasePackFetchConnection.java:379)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackFetchConnection.fetch(BasePackFetchConnection.java:302)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackFetchConnection.fetch(BasePackFetchConnection.java:293)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.fetchObjects(FetchProcess.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.executeImp(FetchProcess.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.execute(FetchProcess.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.fetch(Transport.java:1269)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:237)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
    at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:202)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.force(FileChannelImpl.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.ObjectDirectoryPackParser.parse(ObjectDirectoryPackParser.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PackParser.parse(PackParser.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackFetchConnection.receivePack(BasePackFetchConnection.java:776)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackFetchConnection.doFetch(BasePackFetchConnection.java:372)
    ... 22 more
```